# Wavy red line under a word?

Tags: formatting

How can I style my word so it shows a wavy line under it in a text cell?
(Similar to what MS Word does when it finds a misspelled word)

--- update

or better - displaying a wavy line without modifying the cell

Comment: In TeX? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80378/red-squiggly-imitation

Answer (score 2):

crude..but maybe good for some purpose

```
 Underscript[Style[ Text[# ]] ,
    Style[Text[StringJoin@ConstantArray["~", StringLength@#]], 
         Red]] &@"Hello World"
```

[image]

(To put in a text cell, evaluate, copy paste into text cell, then right-click and set style to output.)

Comment: Nice try! thanks